# Upload from local URL to server

Tags: php, file-upload

Is it possible to send file from a local URL? 
I need to upload files in php from your local url, eg I open the web page with:
 **www ... upload.php?url=c://...file.jpg**,
from the url **GET**,I would get the file on the pc and would upload, without using **html** or anything else that I have to choose, just with the file url.

**Important**, it can only be this way, it will not be possible to choose the file during the upload, it will only be a **POST** or **GET** with the local url.

I researched and found nothing related, if anyone can help

Comment: "_I need to upload files in php from your local url_" What do you mean by "your local url", the client's machine?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I need

Comment: Based on what you appear to be asking: ***no.***

Comment: Imagine if that was possible, then you could just fish for any file on someones computer.

Comment: I want to upload the file to my server but without using HTML choose, I have the url file location on the computer, from it the browser will access esee file and upload to server

Comment: That would be a gaping security hole if that was possible.

Comment: Supposing you are doing that for a local test/learning app, why not then just read it from local location and save it to where you want?

Comment: @Nadjin Mami I'm using construct 2, it has a file chooser but I can not upload from it, just get the file, there's a url of it on the machine, size etc, but I can not upload, only if I open a tab outside. from it make all the html and such, but as it already commits the url on the machine, I wanted to use this to do the direct sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is impossible for server to get a client file by using the file path.

But maybe you can use JS and FileSystemobject to prepare the file, make it to streaming and post to the server.

And you must know FSO need a high security permission and may be disabled on users' browser.